# Debian: Login to mysql doesn't work

Tags: linux, debian, mysql, webserver, phpmyadmin

So I rented this server with Debian 7, and wanted to install a webserver, and followed the following tutorial:

http://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu_debian_lamp_server

And I'm now stuck at the PHPMyAdmin part. Probably the problem is that I tried to install PHPMyAdmin before changing the root password.

So I purged PHPMyAdmin, and currently the problem is that I'm unable to login at all to mysql. So to break it down, the command:

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -p
```

asks me for a password, and the password ALWAYS doesn't work. So I started searching for a solution, and found this one here:

http://myotragusbalearicus.wordpress.com/2011/11/21/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-no/

So I reset the password using the mysql-command

```
UPDATE user SET password=PASSWORD('YOUR_NEW_PASSWORD_HERE') WHERE user = 'root';
```

like a gillion times... and the new password never works! I tried also to flush privileges after the password reset... but no use.

Please advise. This is the first time setting my own server.

Thank you for any efforts.

Comment: did you first kill the mysql daemon

Comment: @GauravJoseph Of course, and started the safe-mode

Comment: You might want to try `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` after the `UPDATE` command

Comment: @GauravJoseph I did that... in fact it's mentioned in the post...

Comment: Did it 3 times now worked every time.

Comment: @GauravJoseph is there a condition on the length of the password or something I have to keep an eye on?

Comment: You can always try with a simple password such as root. And the article you mentioned does not declare the `FLUSH` command or I don't see it!

Comment: @GauravJoseph I did read many articles and that's why I'm flushing priveleges. I'll try a very simple password and see now.

Comment: OK here's another variation of UPDATE. `USE mysql UPDATE user SET password = PASSWORD('newpwd') WHERE Host = '%' AND User = 'root';`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12544/discussion-between-gaurav-joseph-and-the-quantum-physicist)

Comment: @GauravJoseph I tried the last command literally and flushed and the password "newpwd" failed to login... this is so puzzling... what is going on?!

Comment: Thanks to Gaurav, it works now. It turns out that the default root user name was "admin" and not "root".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Gaurav, it works now. It turns out that the default root user name was "admin" and not "root".